# Why is my countdown function not working?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I was so excited for Christmas that I decide what better way to countdown than create a countdown timer to Christmas. But my countdown does not appear to work.

```
let targetDate = new Date(null, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0)

let today = new Date()

targetDate.setFullYear(today.getFullYear())

if (targetDate.getTime() - today.getTime() <= 0) {

    targetDate.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() + 1)

}

let timer = setInterval(() => {

    today = new Date()

    e = document.getElementById("countdown")

    if (targetDate.getTime() - today.getTime() == 0) {

        e.innerHTML = "Horray! Merry Christmas, Everyone! Horray!"

        clearInterval(timer)

    } else {

        distance = targetDate.getTime() - today.getTime()

        days = Math.floor(distance / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))

        distance -= day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

        hours = Math.floor(distance / (60 * 60 * 1000))

        distance -= hours * 60 * 60 * 1000

        minutes = Math.floor(distance / (60 * 1000))

        distance -= minutes * 60 * 1000

        seconds = Math.floor(distance / 1000)

        e.innerHTML = days + " d " hours + " h " + minutes + " m " + seconds + " s "

    }

}, 1000)
```

I have tried console logging the timer value but the code didn't rendered. It appears that the innerHTML code didn't run.

Comment: check what `e` is after `e = document.getElementById("countdown")` .... if your code runs this before the DOM has such an element it will fail ... try putting the javascript at the very bottom of the body element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line

```
 e.innerHTML = days + " d " hours + " h " + mi
```

it should be

```
 e.innerHTML = days + " d " + hours + " h " + mi
```

Comment: +         distance = day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
should be         distance = days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

might wanna add that